# Como trocar o texto de um elemento por ele mais um outro texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Quero trocar o texto de um elemento por ele mais outro texto.
Esta é uma representação do meu código:

**Javascript:**

```
var elementoTexto = document.getElementById("elemento").innerHTML
elementoTexto = elementoTexto + " texto."
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="elemento">isto é um</p>
```

Por algum motivo o `elementoTexto = elementoTexto + " texto."` não consegue trocar o texto do `<p id="elemento">isto é um</p>` para `<p id="elemento">isto é um texto.</p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser assim

```html
<p id="elemento">isto é um</p>
<script>
  var elementoTexto = document.getElementById("elemento").innerHTML
 document.getElementById("elemento").innerHTML =  elementoTexto + " texto."
</script>
```

Qualquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta

Comment: Funcionou, era bem simples hein. Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

É a mesma lógica do código do colega @MagicHat, só estou mostrando uma sintaxe alternativa e o uso de `innerText`:

```js
document.getElementById("elemento").innerText += " texto";
```

```html
<p id="elemento">isto é um</p>
```

### Entendendo o problema do seu código:

Quando você fez isso:

```
var elementoTexto = document.getElementById("elemento").innerHTML
```

simplesmente guardou o HTML do elemento em uma variável `elementoTexto`, e em seguida:

```
elementoTexto = elementoTexto + " texto."
```

acrescentou `texto` nesta variável. Mas não modificou o elemento. Veja como um pequeno ajuste muda tudo:

```js
var elementoTexto = document.getElementById("elemento")
elementoTexto.innerHTML = elementoTexto.innerHTML + " texto."
```

```html
<p id="elemento">isto é um</p>
```

Neste caso, estamos guardando **o elemento** em `elementoTexto`, em vez de guardarmos apenas **seu conteúdo**. Assim, quando mudamos a propriedade `innerHTML`, estamos mudando dentro do elemento de fato, e não apenas uma cópia de seu valor.

Vale notar que, em regra geral, este tipo de construção

```
elementoTexto.innerHTML = elementoTexto.innerHTML + " texto.";
```

pode ser escrito de maneira mais curta

```
elementoTexto.innerHTML += " texto.";
```

Outros exemplos de simplificação de sintaxe:

```
var x = 100;
x /= 2;           // 50     é o mesmo que x = x / 2;

var j = 10;
j *= 10;          // 100    é o mesmo que j = j * 10;

var n = 7;
n += 2;           // 9      é o mesmo que n = n + 2;

var i = 1;
i++;              // 2      é o mesmo que i = i + 1;

var p = 9;
p--;              // 8      é o mesmo que p = p - 1
```